# Raspberry pi 2 I2C0 doesnt' show any device

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi2

im trying  to  use  the I2C-0 on RPI 2   but when  i run   i2cdetect -y 0   nothing  appears    .i pulled up  the  27 and  28   pin   to 3V3  using  4K7  resistors   and  no device detected. any ideas. thx  in advance

Comment: dtparam=i2c_arm=on

dtparam=i2c_vc=on
device_tree_param=i2c0=on
device_tree_param=i2c=on
dtparam=i2c0=on
dtparam=i2c1=on

Comment: Resistance 4k7 is too high. Did you try to use 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3? Because the other i2c bus on Raspberry Pi uses 1k8 pull-up to 3V3.

Comment: but  the Resistors of pull-up   is   up to  10K   with  3.3-5 V   power supply

Comment: ok   i will  try with   1K

Comment: Ok. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Do you have any means to check if your i2c waves are formed correctly? oscilloscope or i2c sniffer? I'm using this product http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-i2cspi/

Comment: nope .i wish  i have one

Comment: Last idea. Have you added the kernel parm bcm2708.vc_i2c_override=1 to /boot/cmdline.txt? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=102130

Comment: yes  i did  but  nothing  new

Comment: Please check my answer below and let me whether it helped or not.

Comment: Just double check. So you connected slave signals SDA to RPI GPIO27 and SCL to RPI GPIO28, right?

Comment: yes  with  ground to ground

Comment: I have one more idea. While dev/i2c-1 works for sure just check if you can detect this slave device on the other bus. Maybe you have some problem with power supply of the slave device.

Comment: the  problem that  the   I2C-1 SCL   is  shorted to ground    and  i don't  know how to fix it  .  that's  why   i turned   to  I2C -0

Comment: if  you  have  a solution  for SCL.1    please   help me

Comment: Shorted to ground? What do you mean by that? I'm using "dev/i2c-1" all the time for my i2c sensors and it works perfectly fine. What's more enabling i2c-1 is trivial.

Comment: ok  when  i run   i2cdetec -y  1   it returns  all  slaves adresses   .so  i went to  test  the  3V3  on the SDA  and SCL   the  SDA  pin   is  with  3V3   but the SCL   is  shorted to ground

Comment: I just realized that you might do not understand some elementary things about these interfaces. If you are able to detect slave devices then for sure SCL line works fine. Try to trigger some transaction. Besides in your other post you attached bit-banging tag. You can bit-bang i2c on every GPIO. These dedicated for I2C are just connected to the ports with HW support for i2c protocol inside the silicon.

Comment: and  what  about   the  i2c-1      the SDA    is shorted to ground   not the SCL   sorry.

Comment: Also not possible because somehow you transmitted slave address to the bus and detected slave device! For sure your pins are working fine if you can detect some slave devices on dev/i2c-1. Get some python example and try to run some demo program and for now forgot about bit banging. Bit banging is needed only if you lack of i2c buses or you need faster transactions that 400kHz.

Comment: no   the I2C -1   is not detecting the Device   it   returns  all  slaves addresses

Comment: damn it seems that the gpio port is damaged..

Comment: do you have free sd card to double check on clean configuration?

Comment: should   i   setup  new  raspbian  on the SD   to check?

Comment: no  need   i  checked the pin  with  a multimeter   and  its  shorted to ground

Comment: I'm checking mine in this very moment and i will tell you what i've got there.

Comment: I've checked SDA1 and SCL1 on my Raspberry Pi 2 board and as I expected both are pulled up to 3V3. I give up sth is seriously wrong with your silicon/rpi board. Good luck with solving your issues!

Comment: so   the  only  solution  is  to  use the bit-banging

Comment: Bit-banging or pursuing dev/i2c-0 enabling. Enabling "dev/i2c-0" is possible for sure but I'm just unable to help you.

Comment: This library does bit-banging tricks http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/